# Automation Approach for module with pre-requisite data

Tags: rest, selenium, automation, cucumber

Currently I am automating a module that requires lot of pre-requisite data before performing the actual action to be tested, using Cucumber with Selenium-Java . I am using rest services to create this data, however it keeps creating bad data as the services keep changing as we are working in a agile project. So need some ideas regarding what should be the automation approach in this case.

** Adding data from UI is not possible as the scenarios require 50 - 100 days back date data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what sort of answer you're after here.

So much of the answer is "it depends" and after nearly 15 years in test consultancy i can advise you this a detailed conversation not a simple knowledge drop and run.

Take just one thought line....

- The API is changing, so load straight into the database.
- The database is complex and cross-linked, so copy production
- Production contains user data, so obfuscate it...

You get the idea - for anything i could suggest it could so easily be rebutted - And that's just one avenue to look at. There also your code structure, environments, execution approach, technology, people and teams, etc...

For a different take on things, have a [read of this article](https://medium.com/@richardedwards26/automation-smells-top-level-test-automation-improvements-for-non-automation-experts-251591f188c8) *(disclaimer - i'm the author)*

The entire article is great but the section you want is "It stinks that maintenance of our automation takes so long and costs so much".
...Does that sound about right? :-)

Paraphrasing from the article - You won't ever get away from test maintenance something you need to get across to the rest of the team is the effort it's taking you. If it takes you a week to maintain the automation for a 10 minute dev change, that needs to be addressed.

Beyond that, a few other ideas that might be worth considering (some are in the article too)- and they're generic, non-technical ideas because **"it depends":**

- if it's ALWAYS changing it's not suitable for automation. Tell people you'll pick it up when it's stable. If needs be, get all the cards that will change the api prioritised so it's done asap and no more immediate changes are needed.
- Do you need all the tests you have? You're (probably) doing automated regression testing, not functional testing. The more tests you have, the more effort it is to carry them forwards. Consider decreasing scope to decrease maintenance.
- Can more of your tests become unit tests? Review what you're testing with a dev and see what they thing.
- You're the QA team but quality is everyone's responsibility. Get the dev team doing the maintenance on such changes. Makes sure working automation is part of the definition of done/complete so that 10 minute card is captured for the full effort it is.
- Use your retrospective to raise it and capture what's going on. The entire point of agile is to feedback, learn and adapt. That's the audience you want to raise this question with :-)